# Compare $\log_34$ and $2^\frac 1 4$

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers

Both $\log_34$ and $2^\frac 1 4$ are somewhere in between $1$ and $2$. I know I can get approximate values but they are difficult to calculate by hand so I conclude it's not the way I'm supposed to do the exercise.

So how can I compare the two numbers without using a calculator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(\frac{5}{4})^4=\frac{625}{256}>\frac{512}{256}=2$, we have $\sqrt[4]{2}<\frac{5}{4}$. Hence its enough to show $\frac{5}{4}<\log_34$. This is equivalent to $4>3^\frac{5}{4},4^4>3^5,256>243$ which is true. So $\sqrt[4]{2}<\frac{5}{4}<\log_34$.

Comment: Works fine for me. Nevertheless, how did you come up with $\frac 5 4$? Is it a some sort of intuition?

Comment: I personally knew that $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.41...<1.44=1.2^2=(\frac{5}{4})^2$, so it was more of a guess. But nevertheless it's always useful in these kind of problems to try to fit in a rational between the number, because it's easy to compare a rational number both with a root as well as with a logarithm.