# How can I compare logarithm and the number?

Tags: logarithms, number-comparison

There are two numbers $\log_3 4$ and $\sqrt[4]{2}$. How they can be compared without calculator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare $\log_34$ and $2^\frac 1 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445196/compare-log-34-and-2-frac-1-4)

Comment: Find a rational number between them. In this case you can use $\frac{5}4.$ Since $3^5=243<256=4^4$ you have $3^{5/4}<4$ and thus $\log_3 4 > \frac{5}{4}.$ Do the same to show that $\sqrt[4]{2}<\frac{5}{4}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not trivial in general case. But for your expression:
$$
I=\frac{\sqrt[4]{2}}{\log_3 4}=\frac{a}{\log_3 a^{8}}=\frac18\frac{a}{\log_3 a}=f(a).
$$

where $a=2^{1/4}$.
Function $f(x)=x/(8\log_3x)=\frac{\ln 3}8 x/\ln x$ is decreasing from $1$ to $e$ (one can show it by taking derivative of $x/\ln x$).

Let's take $b=3^{2/13}$. First, we show that $b<a$ (it's not easy without calculator, but doable):
$$ 3^{2/13} \quad ? \quad 2^{1/4}\\
3^8\quad ? \quad2^{13}\\
6561 \quad < \quad 8192$$
then we calculate $f(b)$:
$$
f(b) = \frac{3^{2/13}}{8\log_33^{2/13}}= \frac{13}{16} 3^{2/13}.
$$
Then we show that $f(b) < 1$ (still doable):
$$
13\cdot3^{2/13} \quad ?< \quad 16\\
13^{13}3^2 \quad ?< \quad 16^{13}\\
13^{12}3^2 \quad ?< \quad 16^{12}\\
13^{6}3 \quad ?< \quad 16^{6}=2^{24}\\
\text{since}\ 13^23=507<512=2^9\\
13^{4} \quad ?< \quad 2^{15}\qquad \\28561 \quad < \quad 32678
$$

Finally, $f(x)$ is decreasing means that if $a>b$, then $f(a) < f(b) < 1$.